# How can an object be both null and not null?

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I thought I had a decent (let's say intermediate) understanding of VBA programming, but this has got me stumped...

Context: some VBA programming for a MS-Access application that I've inherited. This app is FE/BE separated, with BE being a database file stored on a network server.

My initial problem had to do with an ugly exception when failing to open a recordset, and after foraging with the help of Mr. Google, I elected to use the GetAttr() method to test for access to the BE directory.

```
On Error goto ErrConnect

a = GetAttr("\\server-name\directory\")
   If (a <> Null) Then
       MsgBox "is connected"
    ElseIf (a = Null) Then
       MsgBox "not connected"
    Else
       MsgBox "this is interesting..."
   End If

ErrConnect:
    MsgBox "Failed to open remote database at \\server-name\directory\"
    Resume Next
```

Of course the "Resume Next" doesn't really make any sense, but I'm curious as to how my variable "a" can be both Null and non-Null... (I'm always getting the "interesting" message of course).

Is this not very weird ??

**Edit:** (for info, setting a watch on "a" shows it is empty)

Comment: `GetAttr` returns an `Integer`, so why are you testing against `Null`? You should be doing some numeric tests.

Comment: You're right. My apologies, I gave some wrong information: because my 'GetAttr()' call is failing, it's throwing an exception, and in fact my variable '"a"' is empty (I edited the post). That's why I thought I could catch this with a test on 'Null'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null is not a value which you can perform an arithmetic operation on.

```
? Null = Null 
Null
? Null <> Null
Null
```

So as you can see you cannot use Null for the If. It would not be True or False, so your reason for Else being executed always. If you did.

```
If a <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Connected"
Else
    MsgBox "Not Connected"
End If
```

That would work.

Comment: Indeed, that works, thanks. I wanted to avoid testing against 0 because that's the value for vbNormal, but I guess that was just a bad shortcut.
Anyway, "Null is not a value which you can perform an arithmetic operation on." does explain my metaphysical doubts on the Null test :)

Comment: You're welcome. Just that you know so much of the problem can be avoided if you properly Dim variables to the appropriate types. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Not in c#. It seems that truly storing a value as both null and not null would require a computer storing data based on the states of electrons. Then, it can be null and not null until you evaluate it. Once the data is observed though, it would be forced to collapse to one state or another.